# Receive emails according to tickets

Tags: php, imap

I have a ticket system on my website. Each ticket have comments. User can create a ticket and ask a question to admin in a ticket's chat.
 Every time admin posts a message to chat, an email with message is sending to user's email.
The problem is that when user gets the email, he answers it by the mail service (for example, Google or Yahoo), and his answer don't inserts in my db, so in ticket system on the website there are no any comments from user if he not uses ticket's chat.

I need to:

1. Receive emails from mail service (gmail, yahoo, yandex..);
2. Filter users answers to ticket comments from admin.
3. Match each email with ticket.

How can I do it?
I know i may use imap to get emails, but i don't have any idea how to implement points 2 and 3.

Comment: It's a bit of a broad question and I don't have experience with implementing this either, but I *do* know you that should look into the e-mail headers `Message-ID`, `In-Reply-To` and `References`. Make sure your outgoing admin mails have a unique `Message-ID` (that you keep track of somehow) and then filter incoming (reply) emails using the `In-Reply-To` and/or `References` headers. [Here's one example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288795) that elaborates a little more on this, with references to relevant RFCs.

Comment: @DecentDabbler thanks!

Comment: Actually, you should use an SMTP filter, not IMAP.  It is way more straightforward to process emails as they come in, rather than fetch them from a mailbox.